# Google chrome 84.0 does not show HTTP Auth popup dialog on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

It simply shows:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"Authentication required."}
```

Same with Firefox 78.0.2

Is there a setting that will show this again?

How am I supposed to login to sites that require this (such as Couchdb/Fauxton)?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out, it is a Couchdb setting that needed to be changed. Look in the `httpd` section of the `local.ini` file for the following lines and do what it says:

```
; Uncomment next line to trigger basic-auth popup on unauthorized requests.
;WWW-Authenticate = Basic realm="administrator"
```

For some reason it was working fine even without this up until a few months ago. One of my regular system updates, borked it.